# Can Big Parasol stop the extra damage a moves does?

Tags: pokemon

Can the [Big Parasol](https://www.pokemon.com/uk/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/series/swsh3/157/) tool card stop the extra damage a move could do?

> As long as the Pokémon this card is attached to is in the Active Spot, prevent all effects of attacks from your opponent's Pokémon done to all of your Pokémon (Existing effects are not removed. Damage is not an effect.)

As an example of a Pokémon that does extra damage, [Charizard ex](https://www.pokemon.com/uk/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/series/sv03/125/)'s Burning Darkness attack states:

> This attack does 30 more damage for each Prize Card your opponent has taken

Would Big Parasol prevent this extra damage?

Answer (score 0):

As description on Big Parasol says (just for clarifications, I believe card would have same effect without this clarification):

> Damage is not an effect.

Description on "Burning Darkness" attack just specify details of damage, not some other effect of attack. So "Big Parasol" does not prevent damage from this attack. If your opponent took one prize card and you are attacking with "Burning Darkness" his pokémon having Big Parasol you would do 210 damage (ignoring other possible modifiers)

I like description of effects [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonTCG/comments/tgdzvw/question_big_parasol_is_an_item_that_prevents_all/):

> Effects of attacks are effects that are applied externally and
> triggered by an attack. Some examples would be discarding attached
> energy, placing damage counters, and applying Special Conditions.
> Restrictions that can be placed on Pokémon like “The Defending Pokémon
> can’t retreat during your opponent’s next turn.” or “The Defending
> Pokémon can’t attack during your opponent’s next turn.” are also
> effects of attacks.